# Prevent content from scrolling beneath SliverAppBar

Tags: user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I have a Sliver layout with a SliverAppBar on the top that collapses when scrolling down.

The problem is the following:

The content of my Sliver layout scrolls under the SliverAppBar: (undesired)

[image] [image]

Instead I want to forbid scrolling further as soon as my SliverAppBar is collapsed.

This should be the maximum state you could scroll down:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return [
                SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 200.0,
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      centerTitle: true,
                      title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          )),
                      background: Image.network(
                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )),
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  sliver: new SliverList(
                    delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate([
                      TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.black87,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                        tabs: [
                          new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                          new Tab(
                              icon: new Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
                              text: "Tab 2"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Sample text"),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `SliverPersistentHeader` and `_SliverAppBarDelegate` see full code below 
You can copy paste run full code 
detail please reference this https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

code snippet

```
SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), text: "Tab 2"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              snap: false,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      )),
                  background: Image.network(
                    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), text: "Tab 2"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Sample text"),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: why the body will move before SliverAppBar, can let them move together?

Comment: and if change **Center** to **Container**,then scroll the NestedScrollView,it will cause abnormal performance

Comment: After test, my Android emulator still works fine with Container(). only the first time scroll not smooth

Comment: This is very helpful, although why does the Text ("Sample text") still move? How can I disable that

Comment: You need tabbarview

Comment: @chunhunghan If i just want to display a listView,tabbar is just a index indicator,how to display this listView?I try to set a new TabController(vsync: this, length: 1) to the tabBarView，but it throw a exception:`Controller's length property (0) does not match the number of tabs (3) present in TabBar's tabs property.`,so ,any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest post your code to a new question to allow more people to help you. current question did not fit your new request.

Comment: please make sure _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 5); your tab controller length is equal to your tabs number

Comment: I would like to know how to stop the Sample text from moving too.