# Content scrolls below SliverAppBar when scrolling down in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If the page does not have enough content for scroll, then content should not scroll below AppBar.
Here's DartPad link and code.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  final SliverOverlapAbsorberHandle appBar = SliverOverlapAbsorberHandle();
  final SliverOverlapAbsorberHandle disconnectBar =
      SliverOverlapAbsorberHandle();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: const Text('Notes'),
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(text: 'Favorites'),
                  Tab(text: 'Deleted'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: const [
            Text('This text should not scroll below appbar when scrolling down, because there not much content for scroll.'),
            Text('This text should not scroll below appbar.'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: 'Add New',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to make changes in SliverAppBar properties like pinned and floating, but that didn't work.
I also tried [this method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970305/prevent-content-from-scrolling-beneath-sliverappbar) but that is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping SliverAppBar with this:

```
SliverOverlapAbsorber(
  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
  sliver: SliverSafeArea(
    sliver: SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      floating: true,
      title: const Text('Notes'),
      bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: const [
          Tab(text: 'Favorites'),
          Tab(text: 'Deleted'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```